# localizeWithFormat and variadic arguments in Swift

Tags: swift, localization

I am trying to create a String extension to do something like that

```
"My name is %@. I am %d years old".localizeWithFormat("John", 30)
```

which looks like this

```
extension String {
  func localizeWithFormat(arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
    return String.localizedStringWithFormat(
      NSLocalizedString(self,
        comment: ""), getVaList(arguments))
  }
}
```

it give me the following compilation error

> Type CVaListPointer does not conform to protocol CVargType

Anyone knows how to work aroundthis compilation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be pretty simple just change your parameters as follow:

```
extension String {
    func localizeWithFormat(name:String,age:Int, comment:String = "") -> String {
        return String.localizedStringWithFormat( NSLocalizedString(self, comment: comment), name, age)
    }
}

"My name is %@. I am %d years old".localizeWithFormat("John", age: 30)  // "My name is John. I am 30 years old"
```

[init(format:locale:arguments:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithFormat:locale:arguments:)

```
extension String {
    func localizeWithFormat(args: CVarArgType...) -> String {
        return String(format: self, locale: nil, arguments: args)
    }
    func localizeWithFormat(local:NSLocale?, args: CVarArgType...) -> String {
        return String(format: self, locale: local, arguments: args)
    }
}
let myTest1 = "My name is %@. I am %d years old".localizeWithFormat(NSLocale.currentLocale(), args: "John",30)
let myTest2 = "My name is %@. I am %d years old".localizeWithFormat("John",30)
```

Comment: Oups sorry, maybe it wasnt clear in the question, but my goal was to create something generic, using variadic arguments

Comment: Thks Leonardo, this compile but it would not let me translate a a localized string with argument since you are not using String.localizedStringWithFormat

Answer (score 1):

This allows localized string with variadic arguments:

```
extension String {
      func localizedStringWithVariables(vars: CVarArgType...) -> String {
        return String(format: NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: ""), arguments: vars)
      }
}
```

Call using:

```
"Hello, %@. Your surname is: %@.".localizedStringWithVariables("Neil", "Peart")
```

Answer (score -3):

In Swift 3

```
func localize(key: String, arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
  return String(format: NSLocalizedString(key, comment: ""), arguments)
}
```