# how to create macro as function with swift programming language

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Following statement represents defining macro in objective c.

As I know macro is not supported in Swift so I have to use function for that, so can you help and provide me what will be the swift code for the following statement?

```
#define LOCAL_STRING(KEY, VALUE, ...) [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@KEY, !@VALUE), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a String extension (the answer for which [I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914053/localizewithformat-and-variadic-arguments-in-swift)):

```
extension String {
      func localizedStringWithVariables(value: String, vars: CVarArgType...) -> String {
        return String(format: NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: value, comment: ""), arguments: vars)
      }
}
```

So then you can do something like:

```
"KeyNameHere".localizedStringWithVariables("some default value", vars: [])
```

p.s.  the empty array in this vars example should be fine if you have no format arguments in the key/value