# NSLocalizedString with format specifiers in Swift yields garbage

Tags: swift, xcode, formatting, nslocalizedstring

To facilitate easier localizing in a very small app of mine, I have this String extension method:

```
extension String {
    func localized(with values: Any...) -> String {
        // debug values
        for v in values {
            print("\(type(of: v)): \(v)")
        }

        return String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), values)
    }
}
```

My German localization of Localizable.strings contains this key/value pair:
`"WeeksFuture" = "In %d Wochen";`

Doing this:

```
for _ in 0..<5 {
    let localized = "WeeksFuture".localized(with: 3)
    print(localized)
}
```

while having Xcode set to debug the app in German (although this happens in every other language too) prints this to the output window:

```
Int: 3
In 151.456 Wochen
Int: 3
In 186.912 Wochen
Int: 3
In 186.880 Wochen
Int: 3
In 187.264 Wochen
Int: 3
In 187.488 Wochen
```

Obviously, this is all wrong. Why do I first get the correct output of "Int: 3", and then a string with a seemingly random garbage number?

Comment: Related: [localizeWithFormat and variadic arguments in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914053/localizewithformat-and-variadic-arguments-in-swift) and [How to properly use VarArgs for localizing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457503/how-to-properly-use-varargs-for-localizing-strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.localizedStringWithFormat` takes a `String` and `CVarArg...` as arguments. You passed in an array of `Any` - `values` as the second argument. It is forced to convert an array to a decimal number, resulting in the weird result.

To solve this problem, you just need to find an overload that takes an `[CVarArg]` instead. Luckily, there is an `init` overload like that:

```
 return String.init(format: 
    NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), arguments: values)
```

However, `values` is an `[Any]`, which is not compatible with the expected `[CVarArg]`. You should probably change the parameter type.

So your whole extension looks like this:

```
func localized(with values: CVarArg...) -> String {
    return String.init(format: NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), arguments: values)
}
```

Comment: Hi Sweeper - so has there been no advance on this? We're not actually calling `String.localizedStringWithFormat`, and there seems no way to do so, as we cannot pass the variadics into the body of the function as a splatted list. I'm happy to use this approach but it feels like we're trying to reinvent an existing wheel.

Comment: @matt I just looked through the new features of Swift 5.3, and it seems you still can't splat the variadic. As long as you can't splat variadics, you can't call `localizedStringWithFormat` with an array... That said, ideally Apple should have added a `FormattableString` type that is `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation`, like C# does...

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your assessment. I suppose it isn't as bad as I think; your `localized` implementation probably does just what `String.localizedStringWithFormat` does.