# String with format from localized string

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function to display a localized text with parameters:

```
func displayLocalizedMessage(key: String, args: [CVarArg]) {
    someLabel.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(key, comment: ""), args)
}
```

If I call it passing two parameters, for example, `notificationPostTagging` as `key` and `["Joshua"]` for `args` and the localized string is like this:

`"notificationPostTagging" = "%@ tagged you in a post.";`

I'm getting this printed in the app:

```
(
  Joshua
) tagged you in a post.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this. I can't pass the second parameter as a comma-separated list because it comes from some other object.

Thanks

Comment: `args: [CVarArg])` seems strange to me. I would have expect something like: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1414167-init or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1417368-init

Comment: Possible solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27914053/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42457746/1187415

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`localizedStringWithFormat` does not take an array of arguments, it takes a variable list of arguments. So when you pass `args`, it treats that array as only one argument. The `%@` format specifier then converts the array to a string which results in the parentheses.

You should use the `String` initializer that takes the format arguments as an array.

```
func displayLocalizedMessage(key: String, args: [CVarArg]) {
    someLabel.text = String(format: NSLocalizedString(key, comment: ""), locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
}
```

Comment: Hey @rmaddy, the string is still printed as I posted initially because this String initializer you posted uses `CVarArg...` as argument. I had to adapt it to use a second available initializer: `String(format: "Something %@", arguments: args) `. Thanks for showing that option.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the `arguments` label to the 3rd parameter. The answer is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of problem and after spending some hours I solved it with this line

```
textlabel.text = "my_string_key".localized(with: ["store_name"])
```

and my localized string like this
Arabic

```
 "my_string_key" = "إذا كنت قد أجريت عملية شراء بالفعل ، فسيقوم %@ بإعلامنا بذلك.";
```

French

```
"my_string_key"="Si vous avez déjà effectué un achat, %@ nous en informera.";
```

This answer based on swift 5 or above